# faxing from ubuntu 16.04 without a fax modem

Tags: networking, fax

It seems quite extraordinary, but it appears that sending a fax from ubuntu using wireless rather than  a fax modem is actually 
 not a completely trivial exercise.      Searching this forum for help yielded nothing helpful (or maybe I'm bad at searching).       I installed `efax` but it failed looking for `/dev/modem`.  It appears one can fax from   `Libreoffice` but only with a fax modem.    Is it possible to do it without a fax modem?    Thanks very much

Comment: Fraid not, trying to avoid another obselete piece of technology

Comment: Try faxzero, at https://faxzero.com/

Comment: Fabulous thanks!    I looked at this, and it appeared to me that you have to subscribe after a 30 day trial, but in fact not!!

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is to use a internet fax service.  I don't wish to endorse any particular one but they are readily googleable.